# android studio emulator loading but not working

Tags: android, emulation

I have used Eclipse to write apps for android multiple times without issue but I am now trying the new Android Studio which I like but here is my problem.
When I run the app I pick my AVD and then tell it to start. The emulator starts loading and then says paired. Then it starts telling me to swipe up and left and right to display and remove cards. Then it says to put hand on screen to dim the screen, ok well I'm on a MacBook Pro so that don't work I swipe to get past that part sometime I can others I can't. Next it says to touch the clock and say some words which also can't do on my Mac, and that is where the emulator stay it never goes to a home screen and it does this no matter what AVD I choose.  How can I get the Emulator to just plain open to the home screen like it should.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: When creating the AVD, check the box that says "Use Host GPU"

Comment: That did nothing but speed of the load time. It still doing the same thing. After saying it is paired it has cards that say swipe to do this and swipe again etc. like if you actually bought the phone and was using it for the first time. The last two ones it says to touch anywhere on the clock and an action such as "Show me my steps" the other says One last thing To dim the screen, cover it with your palm. This is frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured it out. I remember having a similar problem recently when I was taking an android development class for college using eclipse and sure enough that was it.

So here was the solution eclipse gave same problem. for some reason if you have caught exemptions such as hard coding a string etc. the emulator will not run till you ignore these exemptions or fix every last ! mark in your code. Once you do this the emulator will load and run properly.

Answer (score 1):

In your AVD Manager, edit your AVD and make sure your Target is "Android L" and not "Android X.XW". The "W" stands for "wear" and that is causing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with my AVD. The Android Emulator window just used to pop us and the green bars flowed infinitely. After lots of trial and error I arrived at a solution for my problem. the problem was with the Heap size and the RAM size.
Initially the default heap size was 128 MB and RAM was 1563 , I just changed the heap size to 512 MB and reduced the RAM size( high RAM was making my PC run slow) also I enabled hardware acceleration. And Yipeee, it worked.